# compact import typescripts interfaces

Tags: reactjs, typescript, import, interface, export

I want to write the interfaces in a single .ts file.

How do i import and export interfaces correctly?

The following code is working, but too cumbersome in my opinion:

***myinterfaces.tsx***

```
export interface i1 {
}

export interface i2 {
}
```

***mycomponent.tsx***

```
import * as Interfaces from './myinterfaces'

function func(obj1: Interfaces.i1, obj2: Interfaces.i2) {
}
```

But I would really like to use compact calls.

Whether there is a way to implement such an interface usage:

```
import './myinterfaces'

function func(obj1: i1, obj2: i2) {
}
```

Comment: `import { i1, i2} from './myinterfaces'` ?

Comment: @Titian Cernicova-Dragomir, нes, as an option, but is there any way not to specify the interface that I want to get? And if there will be a dozen of such interfaces - it is inconvenient to use, imho.